# card generator (Vue.js and Bootstrap CSS)

Tags: vue.js

I know how to do this in Angular using JS but I was wondering what are some ways of doing this exercise in vue.js.

1. The page should load initially with two inputs fields — one for number of cards and another for number of rows/columns — and a button to generate the cards.
2. The maximum number allowed for both inputs should be 5.
3. The “generate” button should be disabled if either of these fields is 0 or empty.
4. Each card should consist of randomized, unique capital letters, with no letters repeating on a single card.
5. The card should be implemented as a SFC (single-file component) with a property for the number of rows/columns.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3ca6.png

Comment: What you tried so far ?